# Get Facebook userID from access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get the userID using the access token?

I've seen some answers say https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=abc but I think this is wrong as this gets the details of the currently logged in user, not the user in the access token.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The currently logged in user *is* the user in the access token - if you have a user access token, you're acting on behalf of that user.

The two shortcuts are `/me` and `/app` which are shortcuts for the user of that access token, and the app of that access token

Comment: Say I have the access token, and it's sent to my server. I want to _then_ get the user ID. My server isn't logged in as that user (obviously!), so a request to /me from the server isn't going to get anything is it?

Comment: The access token is specific to the user/app pair. When you pass the access token to your server, and the server uses that access token to make an API call, that API call is made on behalf of that user, via your app.

Comment: The thing is, if I get a completely random access_token from the Authorization section of this document https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/, and pass that as the access token to https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token= I get details about _me_ and not whoever that access token belongs to!? (Really appreciate your help btw)

Comment: That site automatically generates an access token for you to use based on your current Facebook session - you can't access that part of the site unless you're logged in, and the access token you get there is for your account. If you check a call to https://graph.facebook.com/app?access_token=xxxx with that access token you'll see the app that generated it is `{
   "id": "2227470867",
   "name": "Test_console",
   "description": "The Facebook Developer Test console allows you to test API calls and other functionality for Facebook Platform",
// snipped the rest of the response}`

Comment: Turns out the docs were trying to be _too_ helpful! Thanks, really appreciate your help here I've been stuck for days. Could you possibly check out my other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11991926/is-using-the-facebook-access-token-a-secure-way-to-validate-a-user